# Swift: Drag a UIView between two other UIViews

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, drag-and-drop

[image]
As seen in screenshot, I have two stationary green and red views side by side.
Blue view is dragable.

What I want is, when the blue view is dragged between green and red view, to move red and green views and make space for the blue view to be dropped. If blue view is dropped elsewhere, it is to return to its original position.

I am able to drag the blue view, but not sure how to "Detect when the blue view is in between green and red and then drop it in place". Help in swift will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look into UIDynamics

Comment: @Woodstock, I did look into UIDynamics, but not sure what exactly to use from there

Comment: check this out http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/uidynamics-in-swift/

Comment: What do you mean by "in between"? You can detect whether views overlap by using CGRectIntersectsRec. You can get the overlapping rectangle with CGRectIntersection, and use that to determine how much the rects overlap if you want to do that.

Comment: @rdelmar he really wants a UIDynamic style behaviour where the bottom view squeezes in between the top two, snapping type behaviour. It's beyond the scope of a single question.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar, guys I figured it out using CGRectIntersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this (thanks to @rdelmar pointer). 
1) Use 'CGRectIntersectsRec' to test when blue view is intersecting with both red and green. 
2) Move red to right and green to left by half their width.
3) Copy blue view's size to create an invisible new view and place it between red and green.
4) test for when blue view is NOT intersecting with new invisible view, then remove the invisible view and move back red and green.